Which nvidia driver should i choose?
I dual booted Ubuntu in last days and had driver issues.When i opened my laptop and boot the Ubuntu i have like 30-60 seconds to use my laptop.I changed my driver to Nouveau driver (from additional drivers menu) and driver problem solved.But now i have more problems like cant change my brightness or not waking up from suspend mode.I'm thinking this problems are driver problems too.There is a lot of options on additional drivers menu.Which one should i choose.
Laptop Specifications:
Series:Dell G15 5530
GPU:Nvidia RTX 4060
CPU:Intel Core i7-13650HX
Ubuntu release:Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Kernel version:Linux 6.8.0-49-generic

We don't know what Ubuntu product, release & kernel stack you've opted to use (LTS releases have kernel stack choice), as those can be involved in decision. You're usually best with using ubuntu-drivers autoinstall anyway; have you tried it?

@guiverc yes i tried it and it download the same driver. And sorry im new at linux i dont know i need to add that specifications thanks im gonna add them.

What you added was good; I'd have said Desktop which I assume you're using (not Server; Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Server & Desktop use different kernel stacks; though they remain the same for a little longer, Desktop will advance to 6.11 where Server will remain on 6.8)

@guiverc i cant boot Ubuntu now, i just tried 'ubuntu-drivers autoinstall' and saw this is the same driver as i changed. I changed it immediatly but its same again. What should i do

I just deleted driver from recovery mode and its now booting

Which driver are you trying to install?  I'd think a 4060 would best use the latest available -- the 560 driver from the graphics-drivers PPA.

@ubfan1 i tried ubuntu-drivers autoinstall and i think it downloaded the 550 driver. Then i rebooted the laptop and got same issues again (dont booting up and black screen problems). When i deleted driver from recovery mode it booted normally.
